# how to play video with base64 in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, base64, html5-video, ionic4

I'm trying to play my **base64** converted video to play in  but whenever I pass my base64 as **src** to the  it doesn't play I don't know why here's my code

```
 <video  [src] = "fileUrl" style="width: 50%;height: 50%;" autoplay controls>
 </video>

convertToBase64(){

  this.file.readAsDataURL(this.fromDirectory, this.fileName).then(
      file64 => {

         this.fileUrl = (file64); //base64url...
        
         console.log("this.fileURl ========>", this.fileUrl)
      }).catch(err => {
         console.log("Error ===>", err)
    });
}
```

if I paste my video base64 in browser it works file but doesn't play in .
your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load mp4 or any other video format that web supports with this code:

HTML

```
<input #file (change)="importFile($event)" accept="video/*" hidden type="file">
<button  (click)="file.click()"></button>

<video #video src="{{this.selectedFile}}" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

TS

```
  selectedFile: any;
  importFile(event): void {

    const reader = new FileReader();

    if (event.target.files.length === 0) {
      console.log('No file selected!');
      return;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = ((r) => {
      this.selectedFile = r.target.result;
    });
  }
```